# How to use Dagger's 2 @Named qualifier in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Recently I had a problem with `@Named` qualifier in Kotlin. I thought that changing from this:

```
var boldTypeface: Typeface? = null
[Inject] set
```

into this

```
var boldTypeface: Typeface? = null
[Inject Named("bold")] set
```

or

```
var boldTypeface: Typeface? = null
[Inject] [Named("bold")] set
```

would solve my problem. But it didn't, it's not even compiling.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had to update my answer since Kotlin improved a lot. Right now I am using Kotlin 1.0 beta 3

To properly set multiple annotations for a property you have to use `@field` annotation:

```
@field:[Inject Named("bold")]
lateinit var boldTypeface: Typeface
```

Note that I am using `lateinit` here so there is no need to use nullable type `Typeface?`

Comment: CAn you please update the code sample to use the current annotation syntax of `@Inject` and `@Named("bold")`

Comment: @JaysonMinard I would but what exactly is wrong with it? I see similar approach in Kotlin's docs http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Comment: You already did the edit (Jan 5) after my comment to the correct format.